# How to pass an index from md-date-filter attribute of md-datepicker of angular material

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am using md-datepicker as calendar picker and for each calendar I want to set some selectable dates with md-date-filter.

Now on the HTML

```
<md-list-item ng-repeat="rec in recommendation" class="single_listing md-3-line">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
            <md-datepicker required md-min-date="recomended[$index].minDate" md-max-date="recomended[$index].maxDate" ng-model="recomended[$index].date_obj" md-placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" md-date-filter="recomendedFilterDatePredicate"  ng-change="recomendedDateChange($index)"></md-datepicker>
      </div>    
</md-list-item>
```

And on the controller I am fetching this list of days from an array of array `$scope.recomended[index].available_days`

How do I pass this index in

```
$scope.recomendedFilterDatePredicate = function(date) {
    console.log(date)
    var day = date.getDay();

    return $scope.exists(day, $scope.recomended[index].available_days)

  };
```

If I pass it as a parameter from the html it doesn't give the date value.

Answer (score 0):

Pass The Value In this Format

```
recomendedDateChange(recomended[$index].date_obj)
```

Comment: In which attribute? ng-change is working fine. I want to capture index value inside md-date-filter along with the date.